# NpgsqlProvider and ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql, ef-postgresql

using npgsql provider and entityframework i am trying to write a simple ExecuteStoreQuery like this :

```
 var result = BusinessContextManager.Instance.ExecuteQuery(x => x.WrappedObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<DataTable>("SELECT 2+2"));
```

but it fails with the error "Field not found" and the stack trace

```
 at Npgsql.NpgsqlRowDescription.FieldIndex(String fieldName) in ---path\Npgsql\NpgsqlRowDescription.cs:line 204
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String Name) in --path\Npgsql2-master\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 184
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader storeDataReader, String columnName, Int32& ordinal)
```

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? what is field index and so one...

i've tried using alias Select 2+2 as result but still the same error

entiryframework version - 5
npgsql version - 2.0.12.91

Answer (score 1):

after posting the question i found out that it can't be done with TElement being DataTable, so i made my own class (entity) and i am returning that, everything works ok, but i still must ask, can it be done so it returns a datatable? (don't know, some hacks..)